# Multiple jenkins servers on one server

Tags: bash, centos, jenkins

I have installed on one server `jenkins`.
I wanted to separate `jenkins` for administrative and development tasks. 
So the where created 2 configs for administrative and development `jenkins`.
Configs are fine and working well.
Development jenkins is started with default `init.d` scripts.
For administrative `jenkins` i have created copy if original `init.d` `jenkins` script and modified it.
Problem is, that this modifyed `init.d` script starts administrator `jenkins`
 but stops/reboots development `jenkins.`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
###############################################################################
#
# chkconfig: 35 99 01
# description: Jenkins Automation Server
###############################################################################
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jenkins_admin
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $time $named
# Should-Start: $time sendmail
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $time $named
# Should-Stop: $time sendmail
# Default-Start:     3 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Jenkins Automation Server
# Description:       Jenkins Automation Server
### END INIT INFO
# Check for missing binaries (stale symlinks should not happen)
JENKINS_WAR="/usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war"
test -r "$JENKINS_WAR" || { echo "$JENKINS_WAR not installed";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 5; fi; }
# Check for existence of needed config file and read it

# Here i changen path to config

JENKINS_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins_admin
test -e "$JENKINS_CONFIG" || { echo "$JENKINS_CONFIG not existing";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 6; fi; }
test -r "$JENKINS_CONFIG" || { echo "$JENKINS_CONFIG not readable. Perhaps you forgot 'sudo'?";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 6; fi; }

# Here i changed pid and lock files

JENKINS_PID_FILE="/var/run/jenkins_admin.pid"
JENKINS_LOCKFILE="/var/lock/subsys/jenkins_admin"
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Read config
[ -f "$JENKINS_CONFIG" ] && . "$JENKINS_CONFIG"
# Set up environment accordingly to the configuration settings
[ -n "$JENKINS_HOME" ] || { echo "JENKINS_HOME not configured in $JENKINS_CONFIG";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 6; fi; }
[ -d "$JENKINS_HOME" ] || { echo "JENKINS_HOME directory does not exist: $JENKINS_HOME";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 1; fi; }
# Search usable Java as /usr/bin/java might not point to minimal version required by Jenkins.
# see http://www.nabble.com/guinea-pigs-wanted-----Hudson-RPM-for-RedHat-Linux-td25673707.html
candidates="
/etc/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
"
for candidate in $candidates
do
  [ -x "$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD" ] && break
  JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="$candidate"
done
JAVA_CMD="$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR"

# Here i changed cache and log directories

PARAMS="--logfile=/var/log/jenkins_admin/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins_admin/war --daemon"
[ -n "$JENKINS_PORT" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpPort=$JENKINS_PORT"
[ -n "$JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpListenAddress=$JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpsPort=$JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpsKeyStore=$JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpsKeyStorePassword='$JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD'"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --httpsListenAddress=$JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS"
[ -n "$JENKINS_DEBUG_LEVEL" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --debug=$JENKINS_DEBUG_LEVEL"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HANDLER_STARTUP" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --handlerCountStartup=$JENKINS_HANDLER_STARTUP"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HANDLER_MAX" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --handlerCountMax=$JENKINS_HANDLER_MAX"
[ -n "$JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS --handlerCountMaxIdle=$JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE"
[ -n "$JENKINS_ARGS" ] && PARAMS="$PARAMS $JENKINS_ARGS"
if [ "$JENKINS_ENABLE_ACCESS_LOG" = "yes" ]; then

    # Here i changed access log directory

    PARAMS="$PARAMS --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins_admin/access_log"
fi
RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting Jenkins "
        daemon --user "$JENKINS_USER" --pidfile "$JENKINS_PID_FILE" $JAVA_CMD $PARAMS > /dev/null
        RETVAL=$?
        if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]; then
            success
            echo > "$JENKINS_PID_FILE"  # just in case we fail to find it
            MY_SESSION_ID=`/bin/ps h -o sess -p $$`
            # get PID
            /bin/ps hww -u "$JENKINS_USER" -o sess,ppid,pid,cmd | \
            while read sess ppid pid cmd; do
                [ "$ppid" = 1 ] || continue
                # this test doesn't work because Jenkins sets a new Session ID
                # [ "$sess" = "$MY_SESSION_ID" ] || continue
                echo "$cmd" | grep $JENKINS_WAR > /dev/null
                [ $? = 0 ] || continue
                # found a PID
                echo $pid > "$JENKINS_PID_FILE"
            done
            touch $JENKINS_LOCKFILE
        else
            failure
        fi
        echo
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down Jenkins "

        # Here i changed killproc target

        killproc jenkins_admin
        rm -f $JENKINS_LOCKFILE
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        ;;
    try-restart|condrestart)
        if test "$1" = "condrestart"; then
                echo "${attn} Use try-restart ${done}(LSB)${attn} rather than condrestart ${warn}(RH)${norm}"
        fi
        $0 status
        if test $? = 0; then
                $0 restart
        else
                : # Not running is not a failure.
        fi
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    force-reload)
        echo -n "Reload service Jenkins "
        $0 try-restart
        ;;
    reload)
        $0 restart
        ;;
    status)
        status jenkins
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
    probe)
        ## Optional: Probe for the necessity of a reload, print out the
        ## argument to this init script which is required for a reload.
        ## Note: probe is not (yet) part of LSB (as of 1.9)
        test "$JENKINS_CONFIG" -nt "$JENKINS_PID_FILE" && echo reload
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload|probe}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Can you help me to modify script to for proper stop/restart commands?

- OS: CentOS7
- Jenkins: latest(from official rpm repo)

Comment: Have you considered writing a systemd unit directly. This way, there will be much less code and the changes between the two configurations are possibly trivial to achieve once you have the systemd unit for one of the configurations?

Comment: It is default script, that is shipped with jenkins. I edited config, PID and Lock file. And start of service is working. I'm not understanging, why stop/restart takes PID and lock files of other `jenkins` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed a few modifications. There are a number of references to `$0`. That is the [name of the script itself](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) as it is called*. You should best have one script called `jenkins` and one script called `jenkins_admin`, consistent with your naming:

`# Provides:          jenkins_admin`

You also missed:

```
status)
    status jenkins
```

That line might give misleading results and should be jenkins_admin.

I would suggest declaring a variable, eg: `JENKINS_SVC=jenkins_admin` and referencing that throughout instead of renaming everywhere.

There is also a problem with the `PID` resolution:

`/bin/ps hww -u "$JENKINS_USER" -o sess,ppid,pid,cmd`

may results in the wrong `PID` being written to the `JENKINS_PID_FILE`.
There is a comment immediately prior to this line which says:

`echo > "$JENKINS_PID_FILE"  # just in case we fail to find it`, which will wipe the contents of the file before figuring it out. You can fire up both instances and see if both files have the same `PID`.

You have a few ways to fix this, either:

- add a grep to match the process_name (but jenkins also matches jenkins_admin)
- run each instance under a different user - jenkins and jenkins_admin
- change the two names to jenkins_dev and jenkins_admin

* `$0` is the name of the script "as called", so `$0` could resolve to: `/path/to/jenkins`, `./jenkins` or just `jenkins`, depending on how it is is invoked.

Comment: I have checked the `PID` files. There are different `PID's`. But you where right with problem in `PID` resolution. Somehow `killproc` uses `PID` that is found by `ps` and not written in `PID` file. If i solve it, i will edit your post and accept it.

Comment: Also i have changed init script name, so i think there should be no problems with `$0`

Comment: Others rejected your edit to my response: **change script to, `killproc -p $JENKINS_PID_FILE` from `killproc jenkins_admin`**.  If that in fact works, you can Accept my answer and add an "Edit" to your Question. However, I'd also suggest creating an issue against the source of your wrapper such that can be fixed for all.  This is a common wrapper structure, so could be a widespread problem (see [S/E Unix & Linux : How does killproc knows what PID to kill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110959/how-does-killproc-knows-what-pid-to-kill)

Comment: It works. I have heavily changed `jenkins init`  script, to make points to `jenkins_admin` files. Like init name, config, `PID` and `LOCK` files. Thanks for this extra topic about `killproc`

Comment: but the `killlproc` piece had a problem as provided, so you should create an issue (wherever), to have it resolved, for others benefit too.